# PHP Code, Trying to Echo the variables set to decoded json array

Tags: php, mysql, post

I am trying to set variables to "question_id" and "weight" below but when I try echoing the variables that I set to "question_id" and "weight", nothing is echoing.

## var_dump($data);

```js
array(3) {
  [
    "examQuestions"
  ]=>
  array(2) {
    [
      0
    ]=>
    array(2) {
      [
        "question_id"
      ]=>
      string(2) "88"
      [
        "weight"
      ]=>
      string(1) "5"
    }
    [
      1
    ]=>
    array(2) {
      [
        "question_id"
      ]=>
      string(2) "89"
      [
        "weight"
      ]=>
      string(1) "5"
    }
  }
```

## code to echo $quest_id and $quest_points

```
 <? php
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($data);
$quest_id = $data["question_id"];
$quest_points = $data["weight"];
echo $quest_id;
echo $quest_points;
?>
```

Comment: Please show us what ist the input JDON string. Thank you

Comment: read https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($data);
$questions = $data["examQuestions"];
foreach($questions as $question) {
    $quest_id = $question["question_id"];
    $quest_points = $question["weight"];
    echo $quest_id;
    echo $quest_points;
}
```